# MYsql want to fetch title_en if title_es is empty

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table in mysql having two fileds title_en,title_es
If language is ENGLISH then title_en is required and title_es is optional.
If langauge is SPANISH then title_Es is required and title_en is optional while entring form data.
NOTE: This is for data entry.

Most likely one filed will be empty.

In PHP i write dynamic query

$sql='Select title_'.$lang.' from product';

If Language is English then it will be "Select title_en from product".
If Language is Spanish then it will be "Select title_es from product".

For Listing page IF LANGUAGE is SPANISH, i have an issue that for some records(Entered when language was English) title_es is empty.

I know it can be handled by fetching both and using PHP function that will check if title_es is empty then title_en whould be shown.

But i want to handle it in Mysql as all site is complete and at this point client make 1 title required and other optional, which in start was both required.

Please suggest only for mysql solution.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 case when title_es is null then title_en
    else title_es
end as title
FROM product
```

Answer (score 0):

`select case title_en
    when null then title_es
    else title_en end as title
 from product`

If you are not allowing nulls in the fields, then just replace the null with ""

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks you for quick reponse i tried your query but it generate error,, syntax to use near 'from product, any how in the mean while i use almost same logic construct and it works for me. SELECT *,if (title_'.$lang.'="",title_'.$Otherlang.',title_'.$lang.') as title   I can not use Select If:: it generate error, but SELECT SOmeFields, if (title_'.$lang.'="",title_'.$Otherlang.',title_'.$lang.') as title WORKS for me. THANK YOU for HElp